# how to remove an object in multiple photos at once?

Tags: javascript, image, scripting, photoshop, photo

I searched for this. I have a set of images and the same size and format. Is there a way to remove an object from all photos at once. I have read some post it mentioned that can be done by photoshop using scripts. I searched for a long time but no luck.

Comment: But Stackoverflow is about coding, not photo editing

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, I know. There is some way to do this by scripting(Coding). That's why I asked here. Also, In photoshop can use JS automation.